# How does hazelcast request gets routed to right partition?

Tags: hazelcast

I am a beginner wrt Hazelcast and trying to understand the following.

In a normal peer to peer set-up with 3 clusters with each being an individual partition. On a request, how is the right partition picked? Is there any router which helps every request? How is the request served?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hazelcast doesn't use consistent hashing so the answer given by `Jeremie B` is not exactly accurate.

There's a couple of important concepts in Hazelcast:

1. Partitions - by default there's 271 partitions, that are evenly spread among the nodes. Each node owns "primary" partitions and contains backup "partitions".
2. Hash function - allows mapping of the key to partition, so in simplified version it looks like this `hash(key) % partitionCount = partition`
3. Partition table - keeps the mapping between partitions and nodes, or to be more precise between partitions and replicas. The first replica of each partition is the "primary" partition, the second, third... are the backups.

In order to contact the right node:

- a "smart" client keeps track of the "Partition Table".
- it uses the hashing algorithm to calculate the partition where the key is stored.
- it looks up that partition in the "Partition Table" and connects to the node that contains the given replica.

There's also a concept of a dummy client which doesn't know to which node it should connect. The requests issued by a dummy client are routed to the right node by the node it connects to (if it's not the right node by coincidence).

Comment: Where does the partition table reside?

Comment: In the context of a client - the client is a MembershipListener to be notified about the members: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/eef987b9920f3f7b4c506e433b0d067cab9ba93c/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/spi/impl/listener/ClientSmartListenerService.java#L42

Comment: @tom.bujok How could you say that Hazelcast doesn't use consistent hashing? From Hazelcast doc, they are clearly saying , partitions/blocks are done across nodes using  "Consistent Hashing". Please correct me http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch12s03.html

Answer (score 3):

The core of Hazelcast is based on a "Distributed Hash Table", without a master node. It works with two shared knowledge between nodes:

1. On ordered list of node participating in the cluster
2. A hash function

For the 1/, Hazelcast use the list of node ordered from the oldest to the youngest. This information is "easy" to get and don't need to be synchronized through some election. The 2/ is just some code/configuration.

The principle of the DHT is simple: Imagine you have three nodes, ordered A B and C. If you want to know wich node is responsible for a key K, you simply hash the key, and take this value modulo 3. If you have 0, it's the node A, if you have 1, it's the node B, and 2, it's the node C.

Of course, it's only a simplified view of Hazelcast: For example, each structure are split into X partitions, and each node owns more than one partition. Moreover, each partition is replicated. So for each partition, there are one "master" node and several "backup" nodes. But you got the point: no master node, no routing node, every node "knows" where each data belong to.

Comment: Thx for your answer Jeremie! It's correct and goes in the right direction, but it's not 100% accurate (you even mentioned it). I added something that exaplins that mechanism precisely.

Comment: I have intentionally simplified this process in order to explain it more easily, as every dht implementation are based on the same principle, but I don't think it's not accurate, neither it deserves a downvote.